# Silly errors during math exams and effective methods of checking.

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education, gre-exam

I'm sure this is something that all math students experience many times in their career.

I've noticed after completing my exam in the examination room that I would go back upon my paper and find myself not being able to find my mistakes! (believing that I've done everything right, if it was wrong why would I write what I think is wrong)

After the exam is over and the paper is marked! I found that I have made many silly errors as I couldn't find them in the examination room.....

Can this be helped? Have you guys got any checking techniques that you can offer to people like me to **reduce** the silly errors?

The ones known already are:

- **Looking over the exam (not very helpful).** I am looking at the exam with the same frame of mind that made those "unconsious mistakes". So how does one find those mistakes?
- **Sanity checks** for mathematical ranges and etc (those are often hard to come by)

I'm sure this post would be very relevant to people! Please comment and ask me for edits before downvoting.

Comment: So dont write exams.

Comment: I think almost everyone has similar experiences. It's really hard to find your own mistake, in particular during exams.

Comment: It really depends a lot on the mathematical level and type of question.  Are we talking about arithmetic or algebraic topology?

Comment: While a valid question, this is not a question about mathematics.

Comment: If you know you'll have time, write your answers on a separate piece of paper at first and then, when you finish, redo the test, ideally using a different approach than you did the first time.. If you agree both times, you're probably right. Otherwise, go through each approach very carefully and don't stop until you find your flaw.

Comment: Look back over the mistakes that you’ve made that you think ought to have been catchable; are there any *types* of mistakes that occur frequently? If so, you could take note of them and make a conscious effort to look for those specific kinds of mistakes when you’re checking your work.

Comment: Is it just during exams you have this problem, or with homework/practice problems as well? If not it may be more a problem with test anxiety

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem until my first year of graduate school in engeering. Now, it is reduced to a more tolerable rate. Note that a 100% error free is impossible, here are the points that I found the most helpful:
+ write very clear and systematic algebra ( do not skip operations , use parenthesis , use one line per manipulation , and concentrate !)
+ question every result , do not just believe it. Go through the algebra until it makes sense. Often when you know the answer that you are after, you will detect/avoid silly mistakes.
+practice a lot! Really, for some people this skill may take a long time to aquire. Do not stop practicing just because you understand the concept, make sure you can get the right result without mistakes.

You may have noticed that none of this is advice is for an exam per se, but rather for the general skill of avoiding silly errors doing math. For the exam, even though you may be tight on time, try to relax and work clearly and step by step.